# Can't start ubuntu 11.10, Stops at login screen!

Tags: hardware, startup, login-screen, boot-failure

I have been trying to dual boot ubuntu with windows 7 via WUBI on my custom built pc
but without success. When i start the computer i can choose windows or ubuntu i choose ubuntu and when i should get to the login screen the screen just stays purple/pink. Tried safe mode but cant get in there either. I have tried reinstall but did not work either. :(
The second time i install ubuntu the screen was purple/pink and the screen was cut of so the left side was on the right side and right side on left side (hard to describe) Third time installing (The last time) it is just like the first time please help!!!! cant get nowhere without help i am kinda new at ubuntu and its creepy commands. Had ubuntu on my old computer. I think the problem is my hardware so here is my computer specs:

- Amd Fx 6100
- Amd HIS Radeon HD 6950 ICEQ X
- Asus Sabertooth 990fx
- 1TB Harddrive I have no idea the name on it

Please Help me!!

Sorry for my bad English! :D

Comment: I am not the biggest pro round here, but I will wild guess this might be a video issue. You might try with older release of Ubuntu or different flavor of Ubuntu (Lubuntu, for example, AFAIK will not need 3D for desktop) Or when you hit the empty screen - cnt+alt+F1 to go to tty1, login, sudo-apt-get update, sudo-apt-get upgrade, sudo-apt-get dist-update.

Comment: try different bootloading options. at the boot screen where u select ubuntu instead of pressing enter press `e`. a new page opens. there will be a line ending with the words `splash`. add the following words putting a space in between... `nomodeset` & `acpi=off`

Answer (score 1):

I share the same opinion as deckoff. It is most probably a video issue. You may try installing Ubuntu from alternate-cd.

- ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso for 32 bit version, or
- ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso for 64-bit version.

It installs using an entirely-text-based installer, however, it doesn't support installing within windows. You will need a separate partition. (Someone correct me if I am wrong here)
Then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you install from the cd because WUBI has many disadvantages.
Check this link:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=481219 for more.

Glad for helping : )

Comment: not a solution for OP